# ¿Cómo se llama la capa donde se pone el servicio web interno WCF (arquitectura Onion)?

Tags: c#, wcf, arquitectura-de-software

La infraestructura es la capa donde se pone el servicio web externo, pero si mi servicio web (*WCF*) es interno, es decir, yo soy el que expone el servicio. ¿Cómo se llama esa capa?

Answer (score 0):

El servicio web (en este caso WCF) en si es una aplicación por lo que es consumida por otros a través de la capa de infraestructura donde se expone el wsdl.

Hacia la estructura interna del WCF deberás tener las capas:

- Core: Domain model, servicios, interfaces de repositorio, otras interfaces.
- UI: Mvc, etc.
- Test: Pruebas unitarias o de integración.
- Infraestructura: Implementación de las interfaces definidas en el Core.

En esta imagen se ve la estructura (Perdón que esté en ingles fue tomada del blog de jeffrey palermo(1) quien fue el que acuño el termino).

[image: arquitectura Cebolla/Onion]

referencia: (1) http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/